# Center position absolute element inside position absolute parent with max-width

Tags: html, css

I have an `h2` which is absolutely postioned inside a parent `div` which is also absolutely positioned. The parent div has a max width of 350px and what I would like to do is center the `h2` inside it. I don't want to set `left:0` and `right:0` on the h2 as this will stretch to fill the 350px max-width instead I want the h2 to grow in width if more content gets added. Absolutely positioning the h2 is a requirement.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/styler/pen/mAyIt

**CSS**

```
.tt {
  max-width: 350px;
  min-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #8F9924;

  .tt-content {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: #ACC95F;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tt">
  <h2 class="tt-content">This is the content.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is absolute positioning a requirement? You can't do what you are after with absolute position, but you have plenty of other ways to center stuff.

Comment: If your text will be always one line you can try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/boHlC

Comment: Hey the reason it needs to be position absolute is because the text will dynamically change but each time grow up from the bottom each time a new line is taken meaning it needs to anchored to the bottom. Hope that is clear enough

Comment: @Danko yeah unfortunately the text can go on to multiple lines so nowrap isn't an option

Comment: Now like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vAbec :D

Comment: @Danko you're kinda on the right track with this, only problem is this - if there is enough content inside tt-content to fill the max-width parent then it should. At the moment you're example has a fixed width. Thinking this may need some javascript added

Answer (score 2):

You might find that this helps.

```
.tt-content {
   ...
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

reference: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

A fork of your pen: http://codepen.io/jakeparis/pen/CGjni

Answer (score 0):

Center an absolutely positioned element like this:

Assume 500px width element:

```
#heading {
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -250px;/* negative half-width */

}
```

UPDATE: Sorry, should have paid better attention to the question.

If you need dynamic width, then consider relative positioning. Then just use `text-align:center;` on the parent.

UPDATE 2: You'll also need this on your H2 element: `display:inline-block;`
This will make the div width stay with the child content.

Comment: @Danko Thanks for pointing this out. My fault. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
h2{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50%;
}
```